# How to get Actor list by UActorComponent?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I want to get all scene actors filtered by a list of actor components.

Kismet library has [this](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Kismet/UKismetSystemLibrary/GetActorListFromComponentList/index.html).

```
static void GetActorListFromComponentList
(
    const TArray < class UPrimitiveComponent * > & ComponentList,
    UClass * ActorClassFilter,
    TArray < class AActor * > & OutActorList
)
```

But what I need is something like this:

```
static void GetActorListFromActorComponentList
(
    const TArray < class UActorComponent * > & ComponentList, // Note the TArray<> element type
    UClass * ActorClassFilter,
    TArray < class AActor * > & OutActorList
)
```

Are there any functions in the Kismet which has similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primitive component is actually an actor component so you can just copy implementation of this function into your code and replace UPrimitiveComponent entries with UActorComponent.

```
void GetActorListFromComponentList(const TArray<UActorComponent*>& ComponentList, UClass* ActorClassFilter, TArray<class AActor*>& OutActorList)
{
    OutActorList.Empty();
    for (int32 CompIdx=0; CompIdx<ComponentList.Num(); ++CompIdx)
    {
        UActorComponent* const C = ComponentList[CompIdx];
        if (C)
        {
            AActor* const Owner = C->GetOwner();
            if (Owner)
            {
                if ( !ActorClassFilter || Owner->IsA(ActorClassFilter) )
                {
                    OutActorList.AddUnique(Owner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or event make a template

```
template<typename TComponent, typename TAllocator>
void GetActorListFromComponentList(const TArray<TComponent*, Allocator>& ComponentList, UClass* ActorClassFilter, TArray<class AActor*>& OutActorList)
{
    OutActorList.Empty();
    for (int32 CompIdx=0; CompIdx<ComponentList.Num(); ++CompIdx)
    {
        TComponent* const C = ComponentList[CompIdx];
        if (C)
        {
            AActor* const Owner = C->GetOwner();
            if (Owner)
            {
                if ( !ActorClassFilter || Owner->IsA(ActorClassFilter) )
                {
                    OutActorList.AddUnique(Owner);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```